# Show just text when image is not available

Tags: html, css, angular, url

I want to show a text when not a image is available

So I have this css:

```
.msgdownload {
  position: relative;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
}

.msgdownload::after {
content:'';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100% ;
background: url('') no-repeat bottom;
}

.msgdownload > p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

and this I have as html. Comes form C#:

```
    return $"<a href = \"{baseUrl}api/Devices/GetDownload/{model.AttachmentKey}/\" alt=\"Download\"  class=\"msgdownload\"></a>";
```

But when the image is not available want to show just text: download.

Thank you

That you will see the text

This is the icon when it is available:

```
background: url('./images/downloadIcon.jpg') no-repeat bottom;
```

How to change this:

```
   return $"<a href = \"{baseUrl}api/Devices/GetDownload/{model.AttachmentKey}/\" alt=\"Download\"  class=\"msgdownload\"></a>";
```

But If I do this:

```
      return $"<a href = \"{baseUrl}api/Devices/GetDownload/{model.AttachmentKey}/\" alt=\"Download\"  class=\"msgdownload\"><img src=\"#\" alt=\"download\" /></a>";
```

And the image is also available. Then You will see the text and the icon.

Comment: What image? The image that would be referenced here: `background: url('') no-repeat bottom;`?

Comment: yes, So I removed the link to the image

Comment: Well you can't check if a file exists in CSS. So you would probably have to check if the image is available on the server-side (C#), then if it exists add a CSS class to your link and that class would have your background-image style.

Comment: But how to do that?

Comment: But I have the image in the Angular project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved like this:

```
return $"<a href = \"{baseUrl}api/Devices/GetDownload/{model.AttachmentKey}/\" class=\"msgdownload\"><img src='./images/downloadIcon.jpg' alt=\"Download\"/></a>";
```

And changed this:

```
.msgdownload::after {
content:'';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100% ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can not use alternative text for **a** tag except **img**. Maybe, it is which make you in trouble.

```
<img src="..." alt="Text Here" />
```

I hope, it helps you.

Comment: ? But I have alt

Comment: return $"<a href = \"{baseUrl}api/Devices/GetDownload/{model.AttachmentKey}/\" alt=\"Download\"  class=\"msgdownload\"></a>";

Comment: But you are using a link tag. Try with img

Comment: yes, oke, But now I cant download I can't click on it

Comment: <a href="image link">
       <img src="#" alt="alternative text" />
</a>

Comment: oke, But what I have to change in this:  return $"<a href = \"{baseUrl}api/Devices/GetDownload/{model.AttachmentKey}/\" alt=\"Download\"  class=\"msgdownload\"></a>";

Comment: But can you directly edit the link and post it here. Makes it simpler

Comment: So can you edit this link:   return $"<a href = \"{baseUrl}api/Devices/GetDownload/{model.AttachmentKey}/\" alt=\"Download\"  class=\"msgdownload\"><img src=\"#\"  alt=\"download\" /></a>";

Comment: return $"<a href = \"{baseUrl}api/Devices/GetDownload/{model.AttachmentKey}/\" class=\"msgdownload\">
       <img src='./images/downloadIcon.jpg'  alt="Download"/>
</a>";

Don't do this operation with **background-url**.

Comment: I have to change the css?

Comment: Can you update your code. I mean your code fragment.